# index match 3 criteria ignoring duplicates excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I'm trying to return a name from a list of duplicate names based on specific criteria.

I want to return an agent name based on department and manager however the agent names, manager and department appear multiple times due to the data being exported over multiple dates. Can anyone give me an index match formula that ignores duplicate names.

I've had a similar query in the past but i need a slightly different formula.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

After *Department* and *Manager*, I'm unsure what the third criteria is but perhaps you can adjust this formula to suit.

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($2:$9)/((B$2:B$9=F4)*(C$2:C$9=E4)),COUNTIFS(E4:E$4,E4,F4:F$4,F4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I don't think I explained myself very well. I just want to be able to retrieve any of the agent names based on their department and manager whilst ignoring the fact that the names, department and manager may appear more than once. I need the agent names to appear in cell F4 going down.

Comment: The answer is above. If it has one too many criteria then remove one criteria.

Comment: It's not working the way I need it to. The above formula works when there is no duplicate agent name. If Column A for example has 3 different names but the same names show more than once, and the same happens in columns B & C (because they are linked with the names in column A, then i need to retrieve the the 3 names from each column but not retrieve the duplicates from each column. Does that make sense?